# amoeba splitting and biased random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

This question has been asked before (see this: [Amoeba splitting probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894426/amoeba-splitting-probability)), but I've recently come across [this article](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/AmoebaSurvival.shtml#:%7E:text=A%20population%20starts%20with%20a,die%20out%20without%20producing%20offspring.) which uses a biased random walk approach.

Screenshots from article attached:
[image]

[image]

What are the "usual arguments" being referenced here? Confused as to how he did this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hitting probability of biased random walk on the integer line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153123/hitting-probability-of-biased-random-walk-on-the-integer-line)

Comment: yes, thank you!